# Compare Cell Data to Different Workbook Data?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way in VBA to see if an external workbook contains a value from a different workbook?
Essentially, I have a workbook that features a Macro button. In which once the button has been pressed, it will take an email address from a particular cell, A2. What I need is the macro to be able to take the data input from cell A2, and determine if a different workbook contains that email as well. I don't want to hard code the email into VBA because this macro-featured workbook is a template, and will constantly be entering different emails. So this macro feature will need to check this external workbook to see if the inputted email is contained within that workbook. 
I have tried to find resources online but I keep getting compiler errors. So I have no idea what I am doing wrong. The code I currently have is extremely basic, but I figured, from a beginning process, this would essentially be the first steps:

```
Dim workbookExternal As Workbook
Dim cellValue As Integer
Set workbookExternal = Workbooks.Open(path name to excel wb)
Dim worksheetExternal As Worksheet
Set worksheetExternal = workbookExternal.Worksheets("Client_Data")
Dim strEmailRecipient As String
Dim emailValue As String
emailValue = Range("A2") ' Cell where the email is being placed


 If InStr(worksheetExternal.Range("A1:AA100"), emailValue) = emailValue Then ' determining if external 
 ' workbook range contains the email value thats equal to the data stored in A2 of this workbook
 MsgBox ("Success")
 Else
 MsgBox ("Error")
 End If
```

This is just as of right now a basic structure to determine if the code is executing properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `Range.Find`. You can't use `InStr` on a multi-cell range like that.

Comment: This worked out great! My only other question, if happen to know by chance, what function would I use to find the cell location of a particular variable? So once the user inputs the email, it then scans the other doc to see if that email is stored in there. Which I was able to figure out. Now, how would I be able to display the location of the cell of this email? So if the email is: "example@email.om" and that email is store on the other Excel file at cell G6, how would I be able to display in a message box: "Email is at location: G6"? using ActiveCell.Address doesn't work

Comment: `Range.Find` returns the `Range` where the value was found. Then you can just use the `.Address` of that range.

Comment: so if the variable is called emailValue it would then be MsgBox(emailValue.Range.Address)? I keep getting an error stating Invalid Qualifier

Comment: See my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check

Example:

```
If application.worksheetfunction.countif(worksheetExternal.Range("A1:AA100"), emailValue) >0 then 
'your code here

end if
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for `Range.Find`.

```
Dim foundRng as Range
Set foundRng = worksheetExternal.Range("A1:AA100").Find(What:=emailValue, _
                   LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then ' test if the Find was successful
     MsgBox "Email is at location: " & foundRng.Address(False, False)
Else
     MsgBox "Email not found."
End If
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: One last question, and I really appreciate all the help you've been. So, I've been able to find the location of that email address. My workbook is set to where a client's info is displayed across a row. So for client x's emial its on A13, and Client y's email is on B13. Is there a way to, once finding the cell, to add a certain number to find a different set of data within a different column. So, if the email is in A13, could i take that variables location, and then add say like 2, which would then place the location at A15? Or would I have to use the Range.Find method again?

Comment: Sure. You can use [`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) for that.

Comment: thank you so much. This has helped me out tremendously!